# What type of pipe is this protruding through my floor?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, gas

Basically, we are renovating a house we have moved into and undoing countless bodge jobs. After removing the old system boiler hot water tank, we have found a large cap protruding out of the floor by about an inch. Once we remove the carpet from the bathroom (yep)I was wondering if there was anything I can do to either remove or conceal this lump of metal. I’m at a loss at identifying a seemingly random pipe that has been capped and I’m struggling to find ways to identify it.

It has a symbol with a circle inside of a diamond of that helps at all.

[image: Mystery Pipe]

Comment: Are you able to get to what's underneath this floor? Is there a basement or crawl space beneath? Based on location, I would guess either water or an abandoned boiler pipe (but then I *think* there should be a second one nearby - supply and return). Well now that I think about it, could also be gas for a former wall furnace unit. Maybe they wanted more heat in the bathroom. Would actually be more likely if there is no drain or second similar pipe nearby.

Comment: Cut out a floor board and have a look. It'll be easy to repair the floor since you're presumably covering it anyway.

Comment: That's most likely a "clean-out" to allow access to a sewer pipe so it can be cleaned if it clogs.

Comment: Kind of small for a sewer clean out but since it was in the area of the boiler it could be a loop that was modified , can you see what type of pipe it connects to? Black iron could be Gas, in any case I would use caution when opening. There are plugs that are flush that use large square drives 3/4” or Allen wrenches I don’t see them often on the west coast but did in Ohio a few decades back on low pressure steam even purchased a 3/4” ratchet set for them (yes 3/4” not common until you get into big stuff).

Comment: Hi all thank you very much for the responses. I should’ve clarified more, the pipe was never connected to the old boiler or old hot water tank that we removed. It was only when we removed the actual tank and knocked down the plasterboard wall protruding into the bathroom that we found this pipe. I did first think it was an old gas pipe when I saw it. Never even considered it being a ‘clean out’. I think I’ll cal a gas engineer to have a look and see what they think. 

Cheers again for the replies and help chaps.